# Hypothesis: $\sum\limits_{n \in A} ccl_p(n) = p-1 $

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, characters

Let G be a the finite set of integers $1, \dots , p-1 $

One can see, if $|G| = p-1 $ with $p$ prime, then $\forall a \in G: \exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $ a^n = 1$ mod $p$ and $ 1 \le n < p $

I define: $cl_p (a) := n $, I played a bit around with my definition and found something, which made me curious:

I claim:

$A := \{ n \in \mathbb{N} | a^n = 1, 1 \le a <p \} $

$ccl_p(n) : = |\{x \in \mathbb{N} | 1 \le x < p \text{ with } x^n = 1 \} |$, $n \in A$

$\sum\limits_{n \in A}  ccl_p(n) = p-1 $

My mathematical capabilities are rather low, so I could not construct a prove or a counterexample, however I wrote a first java program to test my hypothesis and could not a case, when my hypothesis was wrong. So I am actually quite stunned.(how to attach a txt file (?))

Now I would really like / appreciate any sort of constructive help / assistance in either proving or disproving my hypothesis. All assistance is appreciated. (or recommending a better title)

Code here: http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/4851

Comment: The statement after "one can see" is clearly false.

Comment: $a^n=1$ only holds for $a=1$.

Comment: @Lovsovs, $a$ is in a group, not null

Comment: What role does $f$ play?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, I started reading about characters first, played around with it, thought I found a nice identity, checked with a code (I wish I could upload here anyhow) , however I try to figure what is wrong, reading 5xum posts.

Comment: Before trying to understand characters, I would recommend reading about groups themselves.

Answer (score 2):

> One can see, if $|G| = p $ with $p$ prime, then $\forall a \in G: \exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $ a^n = 1$ and $ 1 \le n < p $

I certainly cannot see that. In fact, that statement is clearly false for all prime values of $p$, because if $|G|=p$ and $p$ is prime, then $(G,\cdot)$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb Z_p, +)$ and your statement is equal to saying that for all $x\in\mathbb Z_p$, there exists some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $n\cdot x=0$ and $1\le n < p$ which is *not true*. In fact, if $n<p$, then $n\cdot x=0$ is true if and only if $x=0$.

Comment: I will double check. Maybe something is ill stated. Code worked though. This is really awkward / making me feel uncomfortable.

Comment: @Imago I don't know what code you have, but you can test it on $\mathbb Z_p$ for any value of $p$. However be careful: the group operation is *addition*, not multiplication.

Comment: What's with multiplication? I rushed things while writing down.

Comment: @Imago What was your group then? Are you in fact considering the integers mod $p$ under multiplication? Or maybe the non-zero integers?

Comment: @Imago But then take $G_p = \{1,a,a^2\dots, a^{p-1}\}$. Now, take $a\in G_p$. Can you find any $n<p$ such that $a^n=1$?

Comment: I considered integers mod p, multiplication as an operation.

Comment: @Imago Your misunderstanding runs pretty deep. You need to read an introductory text into groups.

Comment: I feel terrible now.. and wonder how to salvage this. Where I have gone in wrong in my whole stream of consciousness, in fact I did take linear algebra 1, were good at it, and heard parts of algebra 1,..

Comment: @Imago You have simply jumped in too fast. You should look at any introductory text on groups to get to know the basics. What has happened here is that the integers mod $p$ do not form a group under multiplication (the non-zero ones do, but no longer one of size $p$).

Comment: I know. Jumping to conclusion is very unmathematican like.... I were just beyond joy, cause I thought made a discovery (at least for myself and wondered, if this already had a name) and wanted to share it.

Comment: Then I will try to find the error in my code / improve my idea. For now I put a close vote on my thread.